# The test still read from the real SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, mockito

I have made a simple instrumented test to verify that if the data read from the SharedPreferences is displayed properly on the UI.Both data-retrieving and displaying actions are performed in Activity's onResume()method.
But the problem is,even if I've mocked the preference object and defined the fake return value,**the activity still read data from the real preference**,ignoring `when(...).thenReturn(...)`statement.Does anyone have any idea?

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EditProfileActivityTest {

    @Mock
    private UserPreference userPreference;
    private String FAKE_NAME = "Test";

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<EditProfileActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(EditProfileActivity.class,true,false);

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        //Set fake SharedPreferences
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(userPreference.getName()).thenReturn(FAKE_NAME);

        //Start Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
    }

    @Test
    public void showUserData() throws Exception{
        onView(withId(R.id.name_tv)).check(matches(withText(FAKE_NAME)));
    }
}
```

where UserPreference is a custom class which simply wraps SharedPreference class and contains lots of getters and setters.This is its constructor

```java
public UserPreference(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = this.context.getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}
```

and one of its getter and setter:

```java
public String getName() {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_name), "Guest");
}    
public void saveName(String name){
    prefEditor.putString(context.getString(R.string.pref_name), name);
    prefEditor.apply();
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Simplified version of my original Activity:

```java
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    //...
    private UserPreference userPreference;
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        userPreference = new UserPreference(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        //...
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //...
        String name = userPreference.getName();
        nameEdt.setText(name);  //Display the name on an EditText
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same `userPreference.getName()` statement in your Activity?

Comment: Yes I use the same statement in the original Activity

Comment: @TonyChen can u please show where you are adding values in pref. like you are retriving  with key(using strings) return sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_name), "Guest");

Comment: Actually I save the value from another activity using `userPreference.saveName(NAME)`.I have added the setter in my post for reference

Comment: You've mocked a UserPreference object and defined a fake return value, but i dont see where you inject that mock into the activity that is being tested. MockitoAnnotations.initMocks doesnt do that for you. Where does the `userPreference` object in the activity's onResume method come from?

Comment: I apologize for my incomplete description.Now I have added more details on my original Activity.The userPreference is initialized in `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserPreference` mock is created, but the activity still uses the one created in its `onCreate` method. You need to set that activity's `userPreference` field to your mock.

There are a few ways to do that:

- Add a setter method for the `userPreference` field and call it in your `@Before` method:

  ```
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
      ...
      EditProfileActivity activity = activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
      activity.setUserPreference(mockedUserPreference);
  }
  ```

  This is simple but ugly: you alter the activity solely to accomodate the test.
- Set the `userPreference` field via reflection:

  ```
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
      ...
      EditProfileActivity activity = activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
      Field userPreferenceField = activity.getClass().getDeclaredField("userPreference");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      userPreferenceField.set(activity, mockedUserPreference);
  }
  ```

  This is a brittle test: changing the field name breaks it without compile error. The activity doesnt have to be altered, though, so it is useful when you cant change it.
- Don't instantiate the `UserPreference` in the `onCreate` method. In plain Java i'd add it as a constructor argument, but i don't know if that works as easily with Android. Maybe use a dependency injection framework, they're perfect to use with mocking: [Android and Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135378/android-and-dependency-injection)

Comment: Yes this is exactly the problem! I didn't.inject my `mockedPreference` into the Activity.Since either two ways may change the structure of my Activity and test class,I think I will just clear and save some data to the real preference to keep things simple.Thanks for your solutions anyway!!